# 2D angle components between a plane and a point

Tags: excel

I want to calculate the 2D angle between a point and a plane in Excel. I have a 3D coordinate with a global coordinate system XYZ location 
for example: 49.728 584.046 1.152,
and a 6DoF rigid body with a local coordinate system I set by putting the x and y directions on the principle plane, with z normal and global coordinate system XYZ, roll pitch yaw, and the 3x3 rotation matrix 
for example: X Y Z Roll Pitch Yaw Residual Rot[0] Rot[1] Rot[2] Rot[3] Rot[4] Rot[5] Rot[6] Rot[7] Rot[8] -16 columns of data (ignore "Residual" column)
212.92006 434.94462 833.85142 162.99149 -11.00731 112.493 0.61967 -0.37553 -0.86215 0.34011 -0.90693 0.41744 0.05679 -0.19093 -0.28713 -0.93867. 
Please help me find the xz and yz angle between the point and the plane LCS origin. Should I first put the 3D point into he LCS of the rigid body? Then compute the angle between the body and point? ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED.
3D point coordinate data is in Sheet1: C12, D12, E12
rigid body data is in Sheet2: C12-R12

I dont know where to start, thank you.

I want 2 numbers to come out of this computation. the local coordinate system xz and yz angles. xy directions are aligned with principle plane of rigid body, z is normal to that plane.

Comment: What have you tried to implement this in Excel? Where is the problem exactly? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have only arranged the data in columns. I do not know how to do the transformation, either of the 3D coordinate into the LCS of the body or to compute the angle of the line relative to the plane. I think there could be two ways of finding my solution. 1. transform the 3D coordinate from the GCS into the LCS of the rigid body, then compute the angle between that plane and the LCS relative 3D coordinate. 2. compute the angle directly using the rotation matrix of tee rigid body in the GCS.

Comment: If you're not even sure *how* to calculate it, then https://math.stackexchange.com/ may be a better place to ask this question. Once you understand the logic involved, and if you have problems applying it in Excel, then come back and ask the Excel-related question here.

Comment: Thank you. I am close with working from this method on vitutor, but I am unhappy with it because it calculates a single resultant angle. I need the 2D angle relative to the plane as I see it. 
www vitutor.com/geometry/distance/line_plane.html